# Front ortho opposite way around to expected

Tags: grease-pencil, orthographic

I have a box and have drawn with grease pencil 
F on the front (+Y)
B on the back (-Y)
R on the right (+X)
L on the left (-X)
T on the top (+Z)

Right ortho shows the R
Top ortho shows the T (upside down)
Front ortho shows the B!?[image]

Is this correct? It's extremely confusing.

Answer (score -1):

- You should accept the orientation presented by Blender.
- You should not fight with Blender on this small matter
- I think you should switch to each view and then use the grease pencil
- I think it is more likely that you can work successfully with Blender on a second try ... rather than you have discovered a flaw in Blender.
- You may want to see a tutorial on grease pencil

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Are you saying "Yes this is correct, all 3D applications behave this way" or "No this is incorrect, but that's the way that Blender does it"? Why do you think a tutorial on grease pencil will help?